# Prove that the sequence $\{f(\frac{1}{n})\}^\infty_\mathrm{n=1}$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Say that a function $f : (0, 1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a uniformly continuous function.

I'm trying to prove that the sequence $\{f(\frac{1}{n})\}^\infty_\mathrm{n=1}$ converges.

I'm aware that $f(0)$ can't exist in this context, as it's not in the domain of this function.

I think that the function having uniform continuity means that the limit of the sequence must be continuous also. Of course, by definitions of limits, we can say stuff about the convergence of the series.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Fix $\varepsilon >0$. There is $\delta >0$ s.t. for all $x,y\in (0,1)$, $|x-y|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon $. In particular, taking $N\in\mathbb N$ s.t. $|\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{m}|<\delta $ for all $n,m\geq N$ allows you to conclude that $\{f(1/n)\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: I want to add a point, $f$ is not defined at the point $1$.So be careful while choosing a sequence.

Comment: Cauchy! I didn't even consider using that particular condition.

Comment: Notice that you can even prove that $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)$ exist, and thus that $f$ can be prolonged by continuity at $0$ using the same method.

Comment: Yes of course, $f:(0, 1) \to \Bbb{R}$ uniformly continuous,  $ \Bbb{R}$ is complete and so $f$ can be extended uniformly on the $cl(0, 1) =[0, 1]$

Comment: To better understand this prove this:  *A function $f:(a,b)\to \mathbb R$ is uniformly continuous if and only if there exists a continuous function $g:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ so that $f(x)=g(x)$ if $a<x<b$.*